# How to automatically change a number to zero once it reaches a negative value?

Tags: python, numbers

```
while opponentHealth >= 0 or userHealth >= 0:

        userInput = input()

        if userInput == "attack":
            opponentOne = "Larry"
            userDamage = random.randint(0, 100)
            opponentDamage = random.randint(0, 20)
            opponentHealth = opponentHealth - userDamage

            if(userDamage < 25) and (userDamage > 0):
                print("You roundhouse kick {} in the abdomen and he begins to vomit." .format(opponentOne) or "You punch {} in the stomach and he begins to tear up." .format(opponentOne))
                print("You did {} damage to him" .format(userDamage))
                print("He has {} health remaining." .format(opponentHealth))

            elif(userDamage < 100) and (userDamage > 25):
                print("You drive your foot into {}'s groin with as much force as possible. You hear a high-pitched scream emit from his vocal chords." .format(opponentOne) or "{} is intimidated by you and decides to slap himself mindlessly, in hopes that he will lose faster." .format(opponentOne))
                print("You did {} damage to him; a CRITICAL HIT!" .format(userDamage))
                print("He has {} health remaining." .format(opponentHealth))
            elif userDamage == 100:
                print("{} forfeits... Coward." .format(opponentOne))
                print("You did {} damage to him. INSTANT K.O" .format(userDamage))
                print("He has {} health remaining." .format(opponentHealth))
            else:
                print("Swing and a miss. You missed {}." .format(opponentOne) or "You underestimated {}" .format(opponentOne))
                print("You did {} damage to him." .format(userDamage))
                print("He has {} health remaining." .format(opponentHealth))
        else:
            print("Type 'attack' to attack.")
    continue
```

So this is basically a mini fighting game I'm trying to make (first program ever, besides "Hello World" lol). Whenever the variable opponentHealth goes into the negatives, I want it to automatically turn into a 0 instead. So for instance, rather than it saying "He has -13 health remaining.", I want it to say "He has 0 health remaining." Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not opponentHealth > 0 or userHealth > 0:
and add if ( heath < 0 ) do somthing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
opponentHealth = opponentHealth - userDamage
if opponentHealth < 0:
    opponentHealth = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you assign to `opponentHealth`, just take the max with 0.  For example:

```
opponentHealth = max(0, opponentHealth - userDamage)
```

Comment: this will cause infinite loop cause the health  >= 0 is always true.

Comment: Well, any solution that satisfies the original request would have that problem.  Obviously the `>= 0` tests should be changed to `> 0` tests in the top-level loop.